# Iterate over an array and apply it to a function

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, multidimensional-array

In python I iterate with every column in P which is and 4,4 array with the function "q".
like:

```
P = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0.5, 0], [0, 0, 0.5, 0]])


def q(q_u):
    q = np.array(
        [
            [np.dot(0, 2, q_u)],
            [np.zeros((4, 1), dtype=int)],
            [np.zeros((2, 1), dtype=int)],
        ],
        dtype=object,
    )

    return q


np.apply_along_axis(q, axis=0, arr=P)
```

I get a (3,1,4) array applying q function to the P array. This is correct. But how is posible to save and later call the 4 (3,1) arrays to a dictonary to later apply it to another function printR which needs a (3,1) array.

`printR(60, res, q)`

Should add the the 4 arrays to a dictionary in order to iterate with PrintR or there is another method?

Comment: `np.dot(0, 2, q_u)` - what is this supposed to be doing?

Answer (score 1):

Use `transpose`, `zip` to create the dictionary.

To create 4 of `(1,3)`, simply pass them to dict

```
arr = np.apply_along_axis(q, axis=0, arr=P)

d = dict(zip(range(arr.size), arr.T))

Out[259]:
{0: array([[0, array([[0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0]]),
         array([[0],
        [0]])]], dtype=object), 1: array([[0, array([[0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0]]),
         array([[0],
        [0]])]], dtype=object), 2: array([[0, array([[0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0]]),
         array([[0],
        [0]])]], dtype=object), 3: array([[0, array([[0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0]]),
         array([[0],
        [0]])]], dtype=object)}

In [260]: d[0].shape
Out[260]: (1, 3)
```

---

To create 4 of `(3,1)`, use dict comprehension

```
d = {k: v.T for k, v in zip(range(arr.size), arr.T)}

Out[269]:
{0: array([[0],
        [array([[0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0]])],
        [array([[0],
        [0]])]], dtype=object), 1: array([[0],
        [array([[0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0]])],
        [array([[0],
        [0]])]], dtype=object), 2: array([[0],
        [array([[0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0]])],
        [array([[0],
        [0]])]], dtype=object), 3: array([[0],
        [array([[0],
        [0],
        [0],
        [0]])],
        [array([[0],
        [0]])]], dtype=object)}

In [270]: d[0].shape
Out[270]: (3, 1)
```

**Note**: I intentionally use `arr.size` to let zip trim tuples solely basing on the length of `arr.T`

Answer (score 1):

Correcting the puzzling `dot` to

```
        [np.dot(0.2, q_u)],
```

produces the `ost` in your other question.

I still wonder why you insist on using `apply_along_axis`.  It doesn't have any speed benefits.  Compare these timings:

```
In [36]: timeit np.apply_along_axis(q, axis=0, arr=P)                                          
141 µs ± 112 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [37]: timeit np.stack([q(P[:,i]) for i in range(P.shape[1])], axis=2)                       
72.1 µs ± 500 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [38]: timeit [q(P[:,i]) for i in range(P.shape[1])]                                         
53 µs ± 42.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

That `dot(0.2, q_u)` line just does `0.2*q_u`, which applied to the `P` can be `0.2*P` or `0.2*P.T`.

Let's change `q` to omit the size 1 dimensions, to make a more compact display:

```
In [49]: def q1(q_u): 
    ...:     q = np.array( 
    ...:         [ 
    ...:             np.dot(0.2, q_u), 
    ...:             np.zeros((4,), dtype=int), 
    ...:             np.zeros((2,), dtype=int), 
    ...:         ], 
    ...:         dtype=object, 
    ...:     ) 
    ...:     return q 
    ...:                                                                                       
In [50]: np.apply_along_axis(q1, axis=0, arr=P)                                                
Out[50]: 
array([[array([0.2, 0. , 0. , 0. ]), array([0. , 0.2, 0. , 0. ]),
        array([0. , 0. , 0.1, 0.1]), array([0.2, 0. , 0. , 0. ])],
       [array([0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 0]),
        array([0, 0, 0, 0])],
       [array([0, 0]), array([0, 0]), array([0, 0]), array([0, 0])]],
      dtype=object)
In [51]: _.shape                                                                               
Out[51]: (3, 4)
```

We can generate the same numbers, arranged slightly differently with:

```
In [52]: [0.2 * P.T, np.zeros((4,4),int), np.zeros((4,2),int)]                                 
Out[52]: 
[array([[0.2, 0. , 0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0.2, 0. , 0. ],
        [0. , 0. , 0.1, 0.1],
        [0.2, 0. , 0. , 0. ]]), 
 array([[0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0]]), 
 array([[0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0],
        [0, 0]])]
```

You are making 3 2d arrays, each with one row per column of `P`.

The list comprehension that I timed in [38] produces 4 size (3,) arrays, that is one array per column of `P`.  `apply_along_axis` obscures that, joining them on a last dimension (as my `stack` with axis=2 does).

```
In [53]: [q1(P[:,i]) for i in range(P.shape[1])]                                                                                     
Out[53]: 
[array([array([0.2, 0. , 0. , 0. ]), array([0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0])],
       dtype=object),
 array([array([0. , 0.2, 0. , 0. ]), array([0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0])],
       dtype=object),
 array([array([0. , 0. , 0.1, 0.1]), array([0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0])],
       dtype=object),
 array([array([0.2, 0. , 0. , 0. ]), array([0, 0, 0, 0]), array([0, 0])],
       dtype=object)]
```

The list comprehension is not only fast, but it also keeps the `q` output 'intact', making it easier to pass on to another function.